# Insert submenu with css error

Tags: css, html

I am using this template that doesn't support sub menu natively but i really like its design: [zStartup](http://www.html5xcss3.com/2013/07/zstartup-responsive-html5-theme.html)

The HTML structure of my menu is:

```
<div id="menu">
        <nav>
            <div class="wrap-nav">
               <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

      <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Services</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
</ul>
 </li>

   </ul>

   </li>        
       </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

The CSS for submenu-less version, as in the template is:

```
nav {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1111;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
ul.menu {
    margin: 28px 10px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 48px;
}
ul.menu li:hover,
ul.menu li.current {} ul.menu li a {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.menu li a:hover,
ul.menu li.current a {
    color: #ff9000;
}
```

I added the following to accomodate the submenu with unwanted effects as shown in the pictures:

```
 ul.menu li ul { display:none; list-style:none;top:30px; left:auto; float:right; text-align:left;position:relative; width:200px !important; border:1px solid blue;z-index:10000; }

 ul.menu li:hover > .sub-menu { display:block;    } 
.sub-menu li {display:block;}
 .sub-menu li a {
```

display:block; height:40px;font-size: 0.89em;padding:5px 30px;
}

The width:200px was a desperate move as it refused to show the submenu vertically (i assumed display:block would do the trick).

Anyway, the above codes shows the following result, which is ugly:

[image: First level submenu]
[image: Second level submenu]

Any input?

Comment: my input for you is: format code properly... nobody can read this...

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code. Here are a couple of informations that can help you:

- Rule #1: Always format your code properly. Trust me that will make a difference!
- You are using a `menu` class in your css but there is none in your html (it's an `id` not a `class`).
- I show you below the mechanism of sub-menu in pure css, with that you'll have everything you need to make yours.

```css
ul {
  /* We are removing default styles of ul */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  /* Applies to all li */
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative; /* this will make the sub-menu positionned relatived to the hovered li */
}

ul li + li {
  margin-left: 28px; /* just to space your li */
}

li ul {
  display: none; /* Hides the submenu */
  text-align: right; /* Display sub-menu text on the right */
}

ul li a {
  /* Your styles for the links here I let browser's defaults */
}

ul li a:hover {
  /* Your styles for the links when hovered */
  color: #ff9000;
}

li ul li + li {
  margin-left: 0; /* Remove the margin between li that we applied above */
}

li:hover > ul {
  display: block; /* On hover show sub-menu */
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
  float: none; /* Remove floating for sub-menu li so that li displays one above the other */
}

ul ul ul {
  right: 100%; /* position sub-menu of sub-menu to the left of the parent submenu */
  top: 0;
}

ul ul ul li {
  margin-right: 8px; /* Just so that li inside submenu of submenu don't touch parent submenu's li (it depends on the style you want for your menu) */
}

ul::after {
  /* Clearfix because we've used float on ul */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```